# write_imagef seems to not change any values

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl, glteximage2d

I'm trying to write texture data using opencl and displaying it with opengl. The goal is to compare the performance with and without interoperability. But right now I am failing to generate the texture itself. I first wanted to try to do it without the interoperability:

cl Buffer initialization and kernel creation:

```
this->imageBuffer = new cl::Image2D(*context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, cl::ImageFormat(CL_RGBA, CL_FLOAT), this->width, this->height); //this->imageBuffer is a cl::Image*

//create kernel
this->kernel = new cl::Kernel(program, "simple_kernel");

//set kernel arguments
this->kernel->setArg(0, *(this->imageBuffer));
this->kernel->setArg(1, this->offset);
```

kernel execution (happening in loop):

```
cl::size_t<3> origin;
origin[0] = 0; origin[1] = 0; origin[2] = 0;
cl::size_t<3>  range;
range[0] = this->width; range[1] = this->height; range[2] = 1;

//Not necessary needed, but shows my point
this->queue->enqueueWriteImage(*(this->imageBuffer), CL_TRUE, origin, range, 0, 0, this->imageOutput);

//enqueue kernel with NDRange
this->queue->enqueueNDRangeKernel(*(this->kernel), cl::NullRange, *(this->global_size), cl::NullRange);

this->queue->enqueueReadImage(*(this->imageBuffer), CL_TRUE, origin, range, 0, 0, this->imageOutput);

this->queue->finish();

std::cout << "fancy output: " << std::endl;;
for(int y = 0; y < this->height; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < this->width; x++) {
        std::cout << this->imageOutput[(y * this->width) + x] << ";";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

OpenCL kernel:

```
__kernel void simple_kernel(__global __write_only image2d_t texture, float offset) { //offset is not used for testing
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);

    int2 pixelPos = (int2)(x, y);
    float4 pixelColor = (float4)(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    write_imagef(texture, pixelPos, pixelColor);
};
```

All solutions that I found for similar problems are related to the internal format and format used in glTexImage2D (used at the beginning in OpenGL rendering part) so it might actually be the same problem here, but I am not seeing what I am doing wrong.

The expected result would be a red quad. But it only displays the initialized texture (so white in this case. Or black if initialized with 0.0f. Or grey if initialized with 0.4f). By enqueuing also the writeImage, I was able to narrow down that the kernel seems to not change the buffer at all. If writeImage is commented out it displays a black quad. So reading the buffer seems to work, as it reads an empty buffer in that case (resulting in the black quad).

This is reinforced by the fact, that the fancy output (used at the end in kernel execution part) only prints the initialized values (e.g. 1s or 0.4s. Or it prints 0s when writeImage is not used)

Comment: That's a lot of code, could you mark the place where you see that it doesn't work?

Comment: Well that would be in the kernel execution part the loop printing "fancy output". But I have the feeling it might be the formats within glTexImage2D in the OpenGL rendering part. I hoped that was clear through my text at the end, sorry.

Comment: @Apahdos the whole opengl part is completely irrelevant. you basically trying to figure out why your kernel is not affecting the image2d content. edit your question to include only the parts which are relevant to the specific problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your "fancy output" part is wrong.
Your image has **width * height * 4** float elements. You treat it as having width * height elements.

```
auto pitch = this->width * 4;
std::cout << "fancy output: " << std::endl;
for(int y = 0; y < this->height; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < this->width; x++) {
        auto r = this->imageOutput[(y * pitch) + x * 4 + 0];
        auto g = this->imageOutput[(y * pitch) + x * 4 + 1];
        auto b = this->imageOutput[(y * pitch) + x * 4 + 2];
        auto a = this->imageOutput[(y * pitch) + x * 4 + 3];
        std::cout << r << ' ' << g << ' '<< b << ' ' << a << ';';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Second, your kernel fails to compile on my platform because you mark the image as both `__global` and `__write_only image2d_t`. You should omit the `__global`.

Third is your `clEnqueueReadImage` call. Your row pitch is 0 when its supposed to be `width * 4 * sizeof(float)`.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't see that with the output thanks! The kernel seemed to have compiled on my platform but I'll try it later without the global. I was'n sure how to understand the row pitch. But thanks! I'll have a look at it! But what about the missing CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT extension at the end. Am I still able to use the image2d_t type? When using interoperability with cl::ImageGL and therefore I don't need the clEnqueueReadImage I still have the same effect with the image beeing white (initial values)

Comment: I indeed missunderstood what happens when setting row_pitch to 0 and therefore missed a factor 4 as it seems. Thank you very much for clearing that up. But unfortunatly, even after making the changes, it still behaves exactly the same. I have the feeling it is the image2d_t type which seems to not be supported on my device (NVIDIA GTX 960)

Comment: Nevermind!...device.getDeviceInfo<CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT>(); returns 1. But still this did not fix the problem unfortunatly

Comment: Oh wow... I removed the __global but from earlier tests I had __write_only removed aswell. And it still had a black/white texture. Adding __write_only to the image2d_t variable (and removing __global) actually did the trick. Also for the interoperability where I had the same behaviour.